# C break int to digits and store it in linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have this exercise on linked lists.

I have successfully managed the `create_list()` and the `print_number()` functions, but I can't seem to manage the `listnode_t *int_to_list(int num)`.
Note that the exercise is based on a code template, so anything you see (`main` and extra functions with their arguments) are prefixed.

**We are only supposed to fill in the code inside the function so the code compiles and runs without problems.**

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int digit;
    struct node *next;
} listnode_t;

listnode_t *create_list(int numdigits);
void print_number(listnode_t *head);
listnode_t *int_to_list(int num);


void freelist(listnode_t * head) {
    listnode_t * currentNode = head;
    listnode_t * node_to_free = NULL;
    while(currentNode->next != NULL) {
        node_to_free = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
        free(node_to_free);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    listnode_t *number1, *number2, *result;

    printf("Insert a number\n");
    number1 = create_list(3);
    printf("Insert another number\n");
    number2 = create_list(5);


    printf("First number: ");
    print_number(number1);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Second number: ");
    print_number(number2);
    printf("\n");



    //  convert int to list
    number1 = int_to_list(1024);
    print_number(number1);
    printf("\n");

freelist(number1);
    freelist(number2);

    return 0;
}

listnode_t * create_list(int numdigits)
{
    int number[numdigits];
        int i;
    for(i=0; i < numdigits; i++) {
        printf("Dose to %d stoixeio tou akeraiou: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &number[i]);
    }

    listnode_t * head = (listnode_t *)malloc(sizeof(listnode_t));
    if(head == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    head->digit = number[numdigits - 1];
    head->next = NULL;

    listnode_t * currentNode = head;

    for(i = numdigits - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        listnode_t * node = (listnode_t *)malloc(sizeof(listnode_t));
        node->digit = number[i];
        node->next = NULL;
        currentNode->next = node;
        currentNode = node;
    }

    return head;
}


void print_number(listnode_t * head)
{
    listnode_t * currentNode = head;
    while(currentNode != NULL) {
        printf("%d", currentNode->digit);
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }

}

/* The function takes an integer and converts it to a list.
   The functio returns a pointer to the first node of the list.*/

listnode_t *int_to_list(int num)
{
        int newnum;

        listnode_t * head = malloc(sizeof(listnode_t));
        listnode_t * current =  head;
        current->next = malloc(sizeof(listnode_t));
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }

                newnum = num % 10;
                head->digit=newnum;
                head->next=current;

                num = num / 10;
                while (num > 1 && num < 9) {
                        current->digit=newnum;
                        current->next=NULL;
                }
                newnum = num % 10;

    return head;
}
```

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: You already have a function which creates a list from a sequence of digits (`create_list`). Did you not create that function? If you didn't create the `create_list` function, perhaps you could look at it for *inspiration* on how to create the list?

Comment: 1) `current` undeclared in `int_to_list`

Comment: 2) prototype `listnode_t *int_to_list(int num)` add `;` to last.

Comment: 3) `freelist` does not release the last node.`

Comment: sorry my bad..the code didn't psate correctly. I'm correcting it

Comment: 4) `create_list` does not check if the input is one digit number.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The functions with their arguments are given to us. We have to fill in the code inside the functions. 
I am having trouble taking the int num, breaking it to digits and storing it in a list.

Comment: 5) `number1 = int_to_list(1024);`  `number1` is replaced without being released.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks for the pointers. I will add some defendive code to the create_list later,now it's the least of my problems.

Comment: Well you seem to know how to break the number down into digits. Now all you have to do is to *create the nodes* for each digit. Like is done in the `create_list` function. ***Look at the `create_list` function!*** How does it create nodes? How does it add the nodes to the list?

Comment: 6) `while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }` at `int_to_list`. It is meaningless here because no list has been created.  Also, a new node is required for each divided numerical value.

Comment: Are you expecting the loop ` while (num > 1 && num < 9)` to end when `num` never changes? (And isn't zero a valid digit?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the input `1024` you shall create a **new** list like this:

```
(1, *)---->(0, *)---->(2, *)---->(4, NULL)
```

So you need something like this to build the list:

```
listnode_t *int_to_list(int num)
{
    listnode_t * head = NULL;
    listnode_t * current;
    int first_time = 1;

    while( NOT_DONE )
    {
        if (first_time)
        {
            first_time = 0;
            head =  malloc(sizeof(listnode_t));
            current = head;
        }
        else
        {
            current->next =  malloc(sizeof(listnode_t));
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = NULL;

        current->digit = CURRENT_DIGIT;
    }
    return head;
}
```

What is missing here is `NOT_DONE` and `CURRENT_DIGIT` which I'll leave to OP to figure out. It can be done in several ways. One approach could be to use `sprintf` to convert the `int` into a string (e.g. `"1024"`) and then take the digits from there like `str[i] - '0'`.

Comment: thank you! I was stuck with the logic!